# postgresql_query ansible module not handling backslashes in commands

Tags: ansible

when running yml file, commands containing backslash return syntax error

Is there a way of running commands using backslash?

e.g.

```
- name: 
  hosts: 
  tasks:
    - postgresql_query:
       ...
       path_to_script: db.sql


db.sql
...
\c db
```

Comment: It seems that your problem description is missing significant parts of important information.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation of [`postgresql_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_query_module.html) there is a parameter `db`

```
- name: Run pgsql queries from script
  postgresql_query:
    db: <Name of database to connect to and run queries against>
    path_to_script: <path to a SQL script on the target machine>
```

with which you connect to a database and then run queries from a SQL script.

According your problem description it seems that you try to connect to a database from within a SQL script.